# DirectX 11 Shader Resource Management

Tags: c++, resources, directx, shader, directx-11

I'm creating a shader management system instead of using the Effects 11 library. I have a couple of questions about resource management for shaders.

If I have a Constant Buffer set to a certain register in the shader code, does it need to be set to that register when I set it on the device? What if I have multiple shaders that use that register?

Are constant buffers maintained in memory between draws, or are they cleared? Say for example I have a constant buffer that is not changed from the last draw, do I need to set it again?

Is it slower to set constant buffers one at a time or all at once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to set to that register, think of it as a constant buffer slot.

Yes, it will keep there until you switch it by another.

"Is it slower to set constant buffers one at a time or all at once?"

What do you mean by "all at once"?

Anyway, check this nvidia presentation for great info on cbuffer management:
https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/gamedev/files/gdc12/Efficient_Buffer_Management_McDonald.pdf

Note that pixel shaders and vertex shaders (different shader types) use different registers EVEN if you are using the exactly same "variable" on the hlsl code. Thats handled for you, the thing to note is that to update the cbuffer to the register, you use the pixel shader version of the d3d function(VSSetConstantBuffer vs PSSetConstantBuffer, etc.). Thats for all types of shaders of course.

So for example, in the hlsl code, you can have 2 constant buffers using the same slot(register), BUT, remember to not use both on the same shader..Or, again, you can use the same constant buffer on both shaders, just remember that its not really the same.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. By all at once, I mean there is a function VSSetConstantBuffers that takes an array of buffers as a parameter and sets them sequentially based on a starting input slot. So is it better to set them all at once, or call this function multiple times?

Comment: All at once certainly. That will make any communication with the driver happen at once (not to mention 1 function call vs lots). Its basically the purpose of the function existence.

Comment: Some followup questions:

How do I handle 2 shaders using the same register? Do I need to set the constant buffer inbetween draw calls? What about for vertex and index buffers?

Should each mesh I'm drawing use the same input slot, or should I use different ones? Or are the input slots to allow for different data to be set to the GPU?

Comment: Using the PS/VS/'x'S version of SetConstantBuffer is enough (does not matter when you set it), you obviously wont use 2 shaders of the same tipe on the same draw call. Generally, all meshes will use the same slot, and you will set different VBs/IBs for different meshes (different draw calls for each mesh), on the same slot (the slots for VBs are choosen depending on the input layout you created early..). Think of it as using the same configuration (VS, PS, Slots), different parameters (VB, CBs) when using the same render technique.

Comment: Think of it as using the same configuration (VS, PS, Slots) with different parameters (VB, CBs) when using the same render technique. (my edit time was over, so Im posting another comment)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by same type. Do you mean I won't use 2 Vertex Shaders or Pixel Shaders for the same draw call? Or do you mean I won't use 2 of the same set of vertex and pixel shaders for a draw cycle?

Comment: I'm having trouble putting my question into words. Basically I would like to have a 2 shaders (Each has 1 vertex and 1 pixel shader) where a constant buffer uses the same register. Is it possible to do this efficiently?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60139/discussion-between-icebone1000-and-pghazanfari).